# Class vs Type annotations with Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros

As per the scala [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/11-annotations.html), there are four kinds of annotations:

1. Class annotations: `@ClassAnnotation case class Foo(...)`
2. Variable/Value annotations: `@ValAnnotation val field: String`
3. Type annotations: `field: String @TypeAnnotation`
4. Expression annotations

By using `shapeless.Annotation` and `shapeless.Annotations`, it is easy to get class and variable annotations (1&2) from a case class. How to get type annotations of its fields (3)?

Example:

```scala
@ClassAnnotation
case class Foo(
  @ValAnnotation field: String @TypeAnnotation
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a macro

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def getAnnotation[A]: Any = macro impl[A]

def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  println(weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.annotations) // List(ClassAnnotation)

  println(weakTypeOf[A]
    .member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)
    .asMethod
    .paramLists
    .map(_.map(_.annotations))
  ) // List(List(List(ValAnnotation)))

  println(weakTypeOf[A]
    .member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)
    .asMethod
    .paramLists
    .map(_.map(_.typeSignature match {
      case AnnotatedType(annots, _) => annots
      case _ => List()
    })) // List(List(List(TypeAnnotation)))
  )

  q""
}

import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

case class ClassAnnotation() extends StaticAnnotation
case class ValAnnotation() extends StaticAnnotation
case class TypeAnnotation() extends StaticAnnotation

@ClassAnnotation
case class Foo(
                @ValAnnotation field: String @TypeAnnotation
              )

getAnnotation[Foo]
```

Comment: So no support of type annotations in shapeless?

Comment: @pgrandjean I guess no. Why should there be any? Not all possible macros are present in Shapeless. Shapeless deal with ADT (algebraic data types) i.e. sealed trait + case objects/case classes. If you remove modifier "case" at `Foo` there will be no support for even value annotations.

Comment: I mean Shapeless is about type-level programming, generic programming, dependent types etc. Annotations are from meta-programming.

Comment: Annotations[A, T] is a very useful to extract value annotations from case classes. I was wondering if there was anything for type annotations too. Although it is more meta-programming than generic programming, Annotations[A, T] is included in shapeless. Thanks for the code! I will create a TypeAnnotations[A, T].

Comment: @pgrandjean Yeah, I've seen. Thank you.